I am trying to send a message with my mosquitto library wrapper. The first message is successful, but all messages after that are not
When I try to publish to two or more subscriptions with a client, the program halts and just stays like that. Publishing just one message works.
The wrapper is called Client, which handles handshakes, and the publishing and subscribing functions of MQTT.
I expect to publish a message to a certain topic, and then get a message back. I've tried to debug it with many prints, but I can not figure out where the problem is. Perhaps it is within the subscribe function of mosquitto.h?
Inside main.cpp:
int main()
{
    client = new Client("warehouse");

    // Always connect with the server broker's ip and port, not your own. See report.
    int rc = client->Connect("192.168.1.196", 14152, on_connect, on_message);
    int res;

    if (rc != 0)
    {
        printf("Could not connect. Error code: %d\n", rc);
        return 1;
    }

    // BEGIN USER CODE //

    // Subscribe to a topic. Topics are essentially message routes, \
    an indication of where a message should go. All message routes are - \
    in the report (hoofdstuk: verbindingen). Only use routes that have something to do with your application. \
    When a message is sent to a topic you've subscribed to, you will see that message. 

    res = client->Subscribe("hmi/warehouse");
    // client->Subscribe("crane/mps");
    // client->Subscribe("sortingline/crane");
    if (res != MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error code: %d\n", res);
        return 1;
    }


    // This is a demo. You should have error detections for every subscription, like so:
    // res = client->Subscribe("topic");
    // if (res != MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS)
    // {
    //  printf("Error code: %d\n", res);
    //  return 1;
    // }

    // END USER CODE //

    while(!client->ShouldExit()); // This runs forever until client.Disconnect() is executed.\
                                          Use client.Disconnect() only inside on_message()! \
                                          Only deinitializations are allowed after this line.

    return 0;
}

Inside Client.cpp (only relevant methods):

int Client::Connect(
    const char* broker_ip_addr,
    int broker_port,
    void(*on_connect)(struct mosquitto*, void*, int), 
    void(*on_message)(struct mosquitto*, void*, const struct mosquitto_message*))
{
    if (connected == ALREADY_CONNECTED)
    {
        printf("Client already connected.");
        return ALREADY_CONNECTED;
    }

    mosquitto_lib_init();

    mosq = mosquitto_new(client_id, true, NULL);

    if (mosq == nullptr)
    {
        printf("mosq is nullptr");
        return ERROR;
    }

    mosquitto_connect_callback_set(mosq, on_connect);
    mosquitto_message_callback_set(mosq, on_message);

    int rc = mosquitto_connect(mosq, broker_ip_addr, broker_port, 1200);

    if (rc)
    {
        printf("(Client.cpp) Error with code: %d\n", rc);
        mosquitto_destroy(mosq);
        mosquitto_lib_cleanup();
        return CLIENT_ERR_CODES::ERROR;
    }

    connected = true;
    
    threadMQTT = std::thread(&Client::Loop, this); // attach and execute the Loop method inside threadMQTT

    return 0;
}

int Client::Publish(Message msg, const char* topic)
{
    // Wait for handshake

    handshake.store(ACK_BYTE_SEND);

    printf("ACKSEND\n");
    AckSend(topic);
    // while(handshake.load() == ACK_BYTE_SEND)
    // {
    //  AckSend(topic);
    //  return 0;
    // }
    
    while(handshake.load() != ACK_BYTE_RECEIVE);
    handshake.store(-1);

    // Publish message if handshake was successful

    char serialized_buf[sizeof(Message)];
    std::memcpy(serialized_buf, &msg, sizeof(Message));
    printf("[%s] Published message to topic %s with commando \"%d\"\n", this->client_id, topic, msg.commando);
    int res = mosquitto_publish(mosq, NULL, topic, sizeof(serialized_buf), (void*)serialized_buf, 2, false);

    return res;
}

void Client::Loop() {
    while (!ShouldExit()) {
        int res = mosquitto_loop(mosq, 1000, 60);
    }
}

on_message:
void on_message(struct mosquitto* mosq, void *obj, const struct mosquitto_message *msg)
{
    if (mosq == nullptr)
    {
        printf("Variable mosq is a nullptr\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // BEGIN HANDSHAKE //

    int payload = *(int*)msg->payload;

    // this client sent the ACK_BYTE_SEND byte
    if (payload == ACK_BYTE_SEND && client->handshake.load() == ACK_BYTE_SEND)
    {
        printf("test1\n");
        toSelf = true;
        return;
    }

    // another client sent a byte, most probably ACK_BYTE_SEND
    else if (client->handshake.load() == -1)
    {
        printf("test2\n");
        // another client sent byte ACK_BYTE_SEND
        if (payload == ACK_BYTE_SEND)
        {
            client->AckReceive(msg->topic);
            return;
        }

        else if (payload == ACK_BYTE_RECEIVE)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    
    // another client sent byte ACK_BYTE_RECEIVE, meaning handshake = successful
    else if (payload == ACK_BYTE_RECEIVE)
    {
        printf("test3\n");
        client->handshake.store(ACK_BYTE_RECEIVE);
        return;
    }

    if (toSelf)
    {
        printf("test4\n");
        toSelf = false;
        client->handshake.store(-1);
        return;
    }

    printf("test5\n");

    // END HANDSHAKE //


    // BEGIN USER CODE //
    
    struct Message bericht;
    std::memcpy(&bericht, msg->payload, msg->payloadlen);

    if (!strcmp(msg->topic, "hmi/warehouse"))
    {       
        switch (bericht.commando)
        {
            case HMI_TO_WAREHOUSE__MESSAGE_DATA:
                printf("[%s] received HMI_TO_WAREHOUSE__MESSAGE_DATA.\n", client->GetClientID());
                
                bericht.commando = WAREHOUSE_TO_CRANE__READY_FOR_PICKUP;

                client->Publish(bericht, "warehouse/crane");
                                // this DOES get executed, but inside publish it waits for the ACK_BYTE_RECEIVE byte, which never stops!

        }
    }

    // END USER CODE
}

I've tried to print something in while(handshake.load() != ACK_BYTE_RECEIVE), with success. It seems that it gets stuck there. So that means that the handshake is not changing at all. Putting AckSend(topic); inside the loop does not work, as it keeps executing endlessly. It is as if the other client's on_message function does not respond to anything anymore, since on_message needs to have fired after AckSend().
Note: This is my first question in stackoverflow, so if I left things out please say so.
I expected that the two clients successfully communicated with each other, but it doesn't. on_message function does not get fired anymore.

Where is the code that starts the client loop?

@hardillb I've edited the message. Apologies for the late reply.
